# Find Max for each day in PowerBI and DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to find the maximum route for each day based on the count of cars in PowerBI/DAX.
An example of my data is as follows:

```
 Date         Route      Count
 01-Nov-17     A           10
 01-Nov-17     B           5
 02-Nov-17     A           2
 02-Nov-17     C           22
 03-Nov-17     B           2
```

Hence I want to find the max count of route for each date and display the results of a table like so...

```
 Date         Route      Count
 01-Nov-17     A           10
 02-Nov-17     C           22
 03-Nov-17     B           2
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Fiona

Answer (score 3):

First, define measure for max car count:

```
[Max Count] = MAX( Cars[Count] )
```

If you drop this measure into a pivot against dates, it will show you max car counts per date.

Define second measure:

```
[Max Routes] =
VAR Period_Max_Count = [Max Count]
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX (
        FILTER ( Cars, [Max Count] = Period_Max_Count ),
        Cars[Route], ","
    )
```

This measure will return a string of routes per date that have max count. You need a list instead of one value because of potential ties - multiple routes might have the same max count per period. It's not in your data example, but just to demonstrate this, I added an extra record for the first date:

[image]

The way this measure works:
first, it saves max car count per date into a variable. 
second, it filters car table to select only routes that have count equal to max count for the date. 
third, it iterates over the filtered table and concatenates route names into a list separated by comma.

Answer (score 1):

1. Right-click the table choose `New quick measure`
2. In `Calculation` drop-down select `Max per category`
3. In `Base value` field, drag the `Count` column. In this, the value will be aggregated to `Sum` by default so instead change it to `Max of Count`
4. In `Category` field, drag the `route` column

Voila! Magic happens! The measure that is created, when plotted against the axis `Route` will give `Max(Count)` per Route.
Here is what the DAX will look like:

```
Count max per route = 
MAXX(
    KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('Table1'[route])),
    CALCULATE(MAX('Table1'[Count]))
)
```

(so one can directly use this DAX without wanting to drag but i dont understand the DAX at this moment tbh)

> Lucky reference for me:
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-quick-measures

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated column with formula:

```
MAX = IF(CALCULATE(
        MAX(Table1[Count]);
        FILTER(
            Table1;
            Table1[Date] = EARLIER(Table1[Date])
        )
    ) = Table1[Count]; Table1[Route]; BLANK())
```

Create your table and make a page level filter to show all non-blank values of Table1[MAX].